# BST deletion of node with 2 children by copying right child to predecessor

Tags: binary-search-trees

I try to delete a node, $z$, with 2 children in binary search tree by exchanging $z$'s right child and $z$'s predecessor, $y$, right child, which is NULL because $y$ has no right child, if it had then that child would have been the predecessor. Now $z$ has only 1 child and can be removed in the same way a node with 1 child is removed.

The deletion is done in $O(h)$ because finding the predecessor is done in $O(h)$, and as far as I can see this algorithm is better then the usual implementation of BST delete because there are only 2 cases that needs to be handled with the third resolved by simply exchanging pointers.

So why isn't this algorithm being used? Does it have a fatal flaw that I missed?

Comment: what is the "usual implementation of BST delete"?

Comment: from what I see the usual implementation is finding $z$'s successor, $x$, (which doesn't have a left child), and copy all its data to $z$, then delete $x$

Comment: What is the problem with this algorithm? knowing the predecessor in a BST seems harder than doing this

Comment: finding the predecessor and finding the successor are symmetrical, both run in $O(h)$, and there are variants of the more common algorithm that uses the predecessor instead of the successor but again it copies the data to $z$ then deletes the predecessor/successor as opposes to my idea where we just exchange the right children, i.e changing 3 pointers, then proceed as if $z$ has 1 child